# Onde está o erro no Output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou a utilizar a biblioteca Pandas (do Python).

Abri o meu ficheiro CSV com a função head(),

Porém, o output obtido tem os dados/valores todos juntos.

Onde está o erro/Como posso resolver?

[image: código]

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post reduzindo a um [mcve] e colocando informações textuais como texto e não como imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que o seu csv está divido por ponto e vírgula (`';'`) e não por vírgula (`','`), que é o padrão da função `read_csv`, basta usar o parâmetro `sep=';'`, da seguinte forma:

```
df = pd.read_csv('diretorio_do_arquivo', sep=';')
```

De maneira similar, quanto seu csv estiver dividido por qualquer outro sinal, por espaços (' ') ou tabulações ('\t') basta passa a informação para o parâmetro `sep`
Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação da função:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Já tentei, e não resultou. Também experimentei colocar o engine='python', e novamente não resultou. Obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Pela imagem que você colocou, sua base de dados não é um csv, mas um Excel, nesse caso você deve usar a função read_excel